# Create a graph that automatically adds total values by month

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

[Data Sample Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hvDx.png)I'm using Excel 2016. I want to produce a dashboard graph (visually a doughnut would work best) that shows the amount of money spent each month.

I have a column with dates and a column with money, but can't figure out how to get these to filter between the monthly date ranges and adding up the total spent within that time period.

Data sample:

[image: Data sample]

Comment: share some sample data

Comment: I need to measure the amount spent in each month

Comment: I have tried to upload a sample

Comment: I think I have added a link to the file...

Comment: I am interested in specifically Date and Firm Price

Comment: Can you open the link?

Comment: Many people will not download files from an unknown source. Best to [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1517342/edit) and include the data sample as text.

Comment: To include the data as text, please export the spreadsheet as a .csv file and provide a link to the .csv file. Meanwhile we can look at the data in the screenshot, but we can't double-click to open it in Excel.

Comment: I cant upload a .csv as i am working round restrictions using my android phone to upload. I cant directly upload from my desktop.